# Is it valid to escape html in a href attribute?

Tags: html, escaping, html-escape-characters

Assuming I have the following link:

```
<a href='http://google.com/bla'>http://google.com/bla</a>
```

Is this one also valid?

```
<a href='http:&#x2F;&#x2F;google.com/bla'>http://google.com/bla</a>
```

It works in Firefox, but I'm not sure if this is standardized behavior. I hope the question isn't super dumb!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly valid to do that. In fact, the ampersand (`&`) character *must* be escaped into `&amp;` in order to be valid HTML, even inside the `href` attribute (and *all* attributes for that matter).

Comment: True... old browsers like IE would actually interpret &aaaa as special chars, even without a closing ;

Comment: thank you very much! I didn't find anything about this on the web. But I must admit I didn't search long ;)